# Updating Main UI from a usercontrol in WPF with databinding and multithreading

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, data-binding

I'm just starting with WPF and still don't have all the facts about it clear.

Right now I'm messing around with data binding and threading to update data and represent it on a time basis. I have a mainwindow with 2 textboxs and an usercontrol defined with a thread that starts to run when I click it. In this thread I make calls to 2 properties set in the main window in which I have binded to the textboxes, one by code and another one by xaml.

The problem is that the data binding made by code works while the one made by xaml only works when I update the textbox directly. I have been wondering why, and with some change I made it to work, but I doubt this solution is "correct".

The code is this

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Loaded="Window_Loaded" xmlns:my="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1.Elements">
    <Grid>
        <TextBox Name="Textbox1" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="188,50,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Background="White" Text="{Binding Source=my:MainWindow, Path=datavalue}" />
        <TextBox Name="textBox2" Background="White" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="188,101,0,0"  Text="{Binding Path=datavalue2, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}} }" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" />

        <Label Content="Label" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="202,152,0,0" Name="label1" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
        <my:Test Margin="81,138,346,92" x:Name="test1" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private int MydataValue;

        public int datavalue
        {
            get
            {
                return MydataValue;
            }
            set
            {
                MydataValue = value;

                if (PropertyChanged != null)
                {
                    PropertyChanged(this,
                        new PropertyChangedEventArgs(
                        "datavalue"));
                }
             }   
        }

        private int mydatavalue2;

        public int datavalue2
        {
            get
            {
                return mydatavalue2;
            }
            set{
                mydatavalue2 = value;
            }
        }



        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            datavalue2 = 10;
            datavalue = 15;
            Binding bind = new Binding();
            bind.Source = this;
            bind.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
            bind.Path = new PropertyPath("datavalue");
            Textbox1.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, bind);
        } 
    }

}
```

And this is the usercontrol

test.xaml.cs

```
namespace WpfApplication1.Elements
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for Test.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class Test : UserControl
    {
        private Thread t;
        private int resolution;
        private Stopwatch sw,sw2;
        private delegate void changeIconDelegate(long ib);
        private ImageBrush b;
        private Boolean end=false;
        private int count = 0;

        public Test()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            sw = new Stopwatch();
            sw2 = new Stopwatch();
            b = new ImageBrush();
            resolution = 100;
        }

        private void UserControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            b.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/DataBinding;component/Images/249137482.png", UriKind.Absolute));
            this.Background = b;
        }

        private void UserControl_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ThreadTask));
            t.Start();
        }

        private void ThreadTask()
        {
            while (!end)
            {
                count = count + 1;
                Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, (Action)delegate()
                {
                    Application.Current.Windows.OfType<MainWindow>().First().datavalue = count;
                    Application.Current.Windows.OfType<MainWindow>().First().datavalue2 = count;
                });

                Thread.Sleep((resolution - sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds) > 0 ? TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(resolution - sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds):TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1));
                sw.Reset();
                sw.Start();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If I start the application, as soon as I click on the control, textbox1 begins to update, while textbox2 doesnt, but if I alter textbox2 directly, it throws the notification that it changed, so the data binding is doing properly or so I think.

The questions are:

- Why does it work if modified directly but not with the the call at the usercontrol's thread? I think its related to the declaration of the textbox2 in the xaml file as it searchs for ancestors, while the usercontrol is a child, but I'm not sure how to approach this.
- The propertychanged event works for every property of the class, but isnt possible if doing multi-threading that it takes the incorrect value and mistakes an event for another one?
- I'm sure that i'm not using correctly the specifications of WPF and maybe that's affecting the code in someway, for example when calling mainwindow from the usercontrol :S

Sorry for the big quantity of code and questions but I'm starting to like WPF and I get somewhat frustrasted when I don't get things working. I seached for similar questions, but only found people having problems when they had to update the control properties from the Main UI, not the other way, like me

Answer (score 1):

First don't despair! WPF has a steep learning curve for everyone.

Your approach is correct once the property change has been added. To notify changes in the code you have to raise it to let the UI know. However I find the code a little overcomplicated. I would like to let you know another solution in case you may find it useful

You can put your data in a class and then assign it to the DataContext of your xaml. Once you've done this you are very close to implementing the MVVM pattern which in my humble opinion is the best way to work with WPF. I put some sample code

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Value1}"/>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Value2}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
            myClass.Value1 = 1;
            myClass.Value2 = 2;
            DataContext = myClass;
        }
    }

    public class MyClass
    {
        public int Value1 { get; set; }
        public int Value2 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

For children user controls you can create another class and assign it to the UserControl DataContext. This keeps things together and tidy. Also this avoids the need to do  "      Application.Current.Windows.OfType().First().datavalue = count;" you can just modify your binded class directly

Hope it helps

Comment: You will still need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` for `MyClass` if changes to `Value1` or `Value2` are going to be reflected in the UI - which is the specific problem that the question was asking about.

Comment: Yet, I greatly appreciate both of your answers as it helps me improve how I work with WPF as MVVM is basic for this :)

Answer (score 0):

Doing some testing, I tried to add to datavalue2 property the same condition as in datavalue, thats it, firing the property changed event after updating the value

```
        public int datavalue2
        {
            get
            {
                return mydatavalue2;
            }
            set{
                mydatavalue2 = value;
                if (PropertyChanged != null)
                {
                    PropertyChanged(this,
                        new PropertyChangedEventArgs(
                        "datavalue2"));
                }
            }
        }
```

Surprisingly it worked althought it shouldnt be necessary to use it. I was wondering if this could make some incompatibilities as far as throwing 2 events if I modified it directly, but it worked fine, only one event throwed for textbox2... Still I do feel uneasy for this approach.

Comment: This isn't surprising at all.  Raising the `PropertyChanged` event notifies the consumer that a *single*, *specific* property has changed, and only the bindings for that property would be updated.  Your solution is exactly correct.

Comment: Yes, the problem is that I already had the path and the updatesourcetrigger in the xaml, and it worked perfectly if modified from the window directly without having to fire the event myself. If I updated it from the usercontrol it wouldnt do anything unless I manually fired the event

Comment: Yes: because when your textbox control changes, it fires an event so the binding knows to update.  When your property was changing, you weren't firing any event, so the binding doesn't know to update.